# initializing ng-app with name disables varibles initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

With following:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="show_login=false;count=0">
<button> ng-click="show_login=!show_login;count=count+1">INSPIRE</button>
<form ng-show= "show_login">
     Username <input  type ="text"> <br>
     Password <input type = "password">
      <p> {{count}} </p> 
</form>
</div>
```

My form works fine but when i assign name to ng-app module , form is not working.

```
<div ng-app="demo" ng-init="show_login=false;count=0">
<button> ng-click="show_login=!show_login;count=count+1">INSPIRE</button>
<form ng-show="show_login">
     Username <input  type ="text"> <br>
     Password <input type = "password">
      <p> {{count}} </p> 
</form>
</div>
```

Does that means if i give a module name , i have to do all manipulation and variable initialization through controllers or my interpretation is wrong?

Comment: show your js code. how you define your main module?

Comment: from [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp): _Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application._ , so if you pass module name to _ngApp_ so will be used first from defined, but if you pass module name, than you need define module with this name

Comment: @Grundy..at a time i have only one ng-app. the code is in top is replaced by code below (only adding name to ng-app). So when i do ng-app="demo" it should be auto bootstrapped

Comment: nope, when you add name - angular trying to find module with this name, and if not found do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me. If you set up the module like I did below, it should work

```js
angular.module("demo", []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-init="show_login=false;count=0">
<button ng-click="show_login=!show_login;count=count+1">INSPIRE</button>
<form ng-show= "show_login">
     Username <input  type ="text"> 
     <br />
     Password <input type = "password">
      <p> {{count}} </p> 
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: what is need of this angular.module("demo", []); ? I was not using it.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

This is how you declare a named module to assign as the root scope of an angular application. It is a good practice, as when you make more robust angular applications, you run into the need to set up module dependencies. A good example of this would be if you intend to do routing, you'd need to include _ng-route_ in your application.
So your module declaration would look something like:
    angular.module('demo', ['ngRoute']);
If you left it with a root module, you'd have no way of including those other modules you want to bring in.